# 301 redirect multiple pages to it's relevant page on new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm looking to 301 redirect my old site to my new one. The thing is that i have hundreds of pages so i was wondering if its possible to use some sort of wild card for the domain part? I'm going to use the exact site structure and urls for the new site.

here's example of how the URL's are going to look

```
http://www.example-old.com/articles >> http://www.example-new.com/articles
http://www.example-old.com/blogs >> http://www.example-new.com/blogs
http://www.example-old.com/blogs/1.php >> http://www.example-new.com/blogs/1.php
```

What i'm hoping to do is when someone clicks on any link from the old site they will be redirected to the same page on the new site. i.e.just the domain part will change and the rest of the url will remain will be the same.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: So what did you try so far? You already know about `mod-rewrite`...

Comment: i know how to redirect the old domain to the new one
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example-new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
But i need to redirect each page to its equivalent on the new domain.

Comment: Show your code, and tell us what's missing in your solution.

Comment: Update your question instead of hiding it in the comments!

Comment: @user2334436: `$1` in your target URL is already placing original path in new redirect URL. What is the problem?